# How to invoke Akka helloworld?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, akka

Below is the code taken from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/AkkaScala.pdf

```
import akka.actor.Actor

object Greeter {
  case object Greet
  case object Done
}
class Greeter extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Greeter.Greet =>
      println("Hello World!")
      sender ! Greeter.Done
  }
}
```

In it, it says :

[image]

How can I run this as a standalone within Eclipse ?

I've tried creating a new Run configuration, setting com.example.HelloWorld as the main class with the program argument being akka.Main but I receive "main class not found" exception.

Update :

Based on answer by TheTerribleSwiftTomato I have

1. input akka.Main into the Main class field, and
2. added com.example.HelloWorld as the sole argument in the Arguments tab.

but I receive below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.HelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:67)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at akka.Main$.main(Main.scala:32)
    at akka.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

I have added the akka Maven dependency, is there something else I'm missing ?

Comment: And one more thing: Akka also has HTML documentation, which makes referencing a bit [easier](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/hello-world.html) :).

Comment: The `com.example.HelloWorld` is just an example, you should replace that with the name of your main actor (`Greeter` in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`akka.Main` is not an argument, it is the launcher **class** (i.e. the one that contains the `main` method). In this case, as described in the documentation, it will set up the `ActorSystem` instance and other necessary infrastructure.

So, in Eclipse, you would:

- input `akka.Main` into the *Main class* field, and
- add `com.example.HelloWorld` as the sole argument in the *Arguments* tab.

---

Re *edit*: I see two problems:

- in the snippet you posted in the question, you don't actually appear to have the [`HelloWorld` class from the example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/hello-world.html). Did you remember to include in your project?
- even if you did remember to include it, there's a slight error in the `HelloWorld` class. It's missing the package declaration:

`package com.example`

Correct that (move it to the right package) and you should be on your way to writing Actor systems.

Comment: yes that was the issue, also in the Scala doc the package is not mentioned in the source code even though its mentioned in the doc

Comment: @Adrian: Glad I helped :). As a final remark, note that the `HelloWolrd` Actor is actually the one that starts the entire exchange (it sends the initial message on the `preStart` hook call).